# send as event name causes stack level too deep after Ruby 3.2 and Rails 7.0 upgrade

Tags: state-machine, ruby-on-rails-7, ruby-3

I am updating the Ruby and Rails to 3.2 and 7.0 respectively. We have a couple of models with `send` as the state event.

After the upgrade this is causing the `stack level too deep` issue.

One option is to use some other name for the send event and this requires a lot of code changes.

Is there a workaround that allows using the `send` as the state event?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/